# Deny access to a PHP file (Nginx)

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, nginx, webserver

I want Nginx to deny access to a specific PHP file, let's call it `donotexposeme.php`, but it doesn't seem to work, the PHP script is run as usual. Here is what I have in the config file:

```
location / {
    root /var/www/public_html;
    index index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location /donotexposeme.php {
    deny all;
}
```

Of course, I do `sudo service nginx reload` (or `restart`) each time I edit the config.

Comment: Have you tried moving the declaration *above* the `location ~` ?

Comment: @Jack Yes, just now. Same thing.

Comment: Alternatively, use `location ^~ /donotexposeme.php`

Comment: @Jack That one worked, thank you. Could you give a hint why? (maybe in an answer)

Comment: If you don't want the existence of donotexposeme.php exposed, why are you returning a 403 instead of a 404?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The order in which nginx determines which location matches can be found here:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location

Using either of these will be matched before any other regular expression:

```
location = /donotexposeme.php
```

Or

```
location ^~ /donotexposeme\.php
```

The first is an exact match whereas the latter is a regular expression prefix match.

Comment: There is a small typo in your example: Since using regular expression match the period has to be escaped to match literally: `location ^~ /donotexposeme\.php`